# JavaScript runtime error: Cannot assign to a function result

Tags: javascript, gridview

HI I am extremely new to Javascript and I am having a problem with updating a text box within gridview.

here is my current attempt

```
 function startCalc() {
        var grid = document.getElementById("GridView1");
        for (var i = 0; i < grid.rows.length - 1; i++) {
            var rate = $("Span[id*=Rate]");
            var qty = $("input[id*=TextAmount]");
            var ra = parseFloat(rate[i].textContent);                        
            $("input[id*=TextVat]") = qty[i].value * parseFloat(rate[i].textContent);

        }
         }
```

However I keep getting an error saying that Cannot assign to a function result.

any help would be appreciated

below is the piece of code from my gridview where essentially I want to multiply the TextBox ID="TextAmount" by Label ID="Rate" and put the result into TextBox ID="TextVat"

```
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="138px" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Groove" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="item" HeaderText="item" SortExpression="item" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vat" SortExpression="Vat">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Vat") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Rate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Vat") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
                        <ItemTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="TextQuantity" runat="server"  class="calculate" onchange="calculate()" Text="0" ></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
                        <ItemTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="TextAmount" runat="server"  class="calc" onchange="calc()" Text="0" ></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vat Amount">
                        <ItemTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="TextVat" runat="server"   ></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
                <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4B4B4B" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#242121" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect that assignment to do? Are you trying to set the *value* of an element?

Comment: I am trying to multiply 2 columns and have the result in a third column.

Answer (score 1):

To assign values to input elements with jquery, you should use the [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method:

```
$('input').val(your value);
```

thus to fix your problem the code should be:

```
var vatValue = qty[i].value * parseFloat(rate[i].textContent);
$('input[id*="TextVat"]').val(vatValue);
```

Comment: Thank you Alex,  I no longer get the error but for some reason the textbox whose id =TextVat does not update.  Any reason why?

Comment: you can console.log($('input[id*=TextVat]')); to see if your CSS selector is working. If the object that is spit out by the console.log has a length property equal to 0, then your css selector does not work. Also console.log(vatValue) to see if this has the value you expect.

Comment: ok so i get the required output from console.log(vatValue)  and I also get length = 17 which would be correct so I am not sure why it is not updating for me